# Error: Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

Tags: java, php, web-services

I am working on a project that requires technologies in both Java and PHP. I use Java to implement my business logic and data source management while the PHP helps to consume the web service I provided using Java. 
My problem:
When I consume a response from the web service and the result contains more than one return collection, the program runs fine. 
(http://driesmeers.mamca.be/images/successpage.png)
However once the result return only one collective response, i get an error as shown below. 
(http://driesmeers.mamca.be/images/errorpage.png)

Here are my code.PHP

```
<?php
  try {
$wsdl_url = 'http://localhost:8080/Mamca/MamcaWS?WSDL';
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url);
$params = array(
    'projectid' => $_SESSION['projectID'],
);
$return = $client->getAlternativeListByProjectID($params);
if (isset($return->return)) {
    foreach ($return->return as $eachItem) {
        echo "<tr align='center'>";
        echo "<td align='left' class='rowDisplay'> <a href = '#' class = 'rowNumber2'>" . $eachItem->alternativedescription . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td align='left' class='rowDisplay'>" . $eachItem->alternativeGroup . "</td>";
        echo "<td align='left' class='rowDisplay'>";
        echo ($eachItem->status === 1 ? 'Active' : 'Inactive');
        echo "</td>";
        echo "<td align='center' class='rowDisplay'><img src = '../images/icons/delete.png' longdesc = 'http://.delete' /><img src = '../images/icons/table_edit.png' width = '16' height = '16' /></td>";
        echo "</tr>";
    }
}
} catch (Exception $e) {
echo "Exception occured: " . $e;
}
?>

<tr  id="ajax_response">                                         
</tr>
```

Response from WS with error output:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP-ENV:Header/>
<S:Body>
    <ns2:getAlternativeListByProjectIDResponse xmlns:ns2="http://services.mamca.be.vub/">
        <return>
            <alternativeGroup>testt</alternativeGroup>
            <alternativedescription>testtt</alternativedescription>
            <alternativeid>10670</alternativeid>
            <id>19</id>
            <projectid>12313</projectid>
            <status>1</status>
        </return>
    </ns2:getAlternativeListByProjectIDResponse>
</S:Body>
 </S:Envelope>
```

How do i resolve this error? thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the result is one single element, SOAPClient doesn't return an array by default, but an object.

You can set SOAPClient to return always an array, even when the result is one element, adding this parameter on instantiation:

```
$client = new SOAPClient($wsdl_url ,array(
  "features" => SOAP_SINGLE_ELEMENT_ARRAYS
));
```